# Macbook pro not showing login screen after uninstalling SAASPass

Tags: apple-login

Today i installed SaasPass and uninstalled it using saaspassremove app from my Macbook pro. After restart my macbook is not showing anything except mouse pointer, no user profiles no password input. Is there anyone who faced the same issue? What can I do now to log into my laptop, please help.